# Why does my windows forms app access the internet?

Tags: winforms

As far as I know, I have added no internet access in my .net windows forms application. But every so often it attempts an outgoing connection to 239.255.255.250. I have no idea why this is happening. Is it something in the .net framework?

Info for 239.255.255.250:

```
OrgName:    Internet Assigned Numbers Authority 
OrgID:      IANA
Address:    4676 Admiralty Way, Suite 330
City:       Marina del Rey
StateProv:  CA
PostalCode: 90292-6695
Country:    US

NetRange:   224.0.0.0 - 239.255.255.255 
CIDR:       224.0.0.0/4 
NetName:    MCAST-NET
NetHandle:  NET-224-0-0-0-1
Parent:     
NetType:    IANA Special Use
NameServer: FLAG.EP.NET
NameServer: STRUL.STUPI.SE
NameServer: NS.ISI.EDU
NameServer: NIC.NEAR.NET
Comment:    This block is reserved for special purposes.
Comment:    Please see RFC 3171 for additional information.
Comment:    
RegDate:    1991-05-22
Updated:    2002-09-16
```

Comment: Is your application digitally signed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess it isn't a big deal. References for your viewing pleasure:

- http://www.nthelp.com/upnpscrewup.htm
- http://forums.snapstream.com/vb/showthread.php?p=129675
- http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=239.255.255.250&btnG=Google+Search

Questions for you:

- How do you know it's your windows app? **ZoneAlarm.**
- Are you using multicast for anything? **No.**
- Are you running any multicast apps or apps that might use uPNP? **No.**
- Are you doing *any* networking with your app? If so, what classes are you using?

Try this the next time you see the alert:

```
Start> Run> cmd.exe:
netstat /b /o
```

That might give you more information on where the alert is coming from.

Comment: Some of the top results are other ZoneAlarm users with the same complaint. I wouldn't worry about it. It's not likely *your* app that's doing it, anyway. Zone Alarm tends to be overly aggressive with its alerts, IMO.

Comment: Instead o netstat, try tcpview.  It's basically a netstat GUI, and it's much easier to deal with.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx

Answer (score 1):

^^Beaten to it

Do you have UPnP enabled on your computer? This is the main cause of Windows trying to access that IP address.

Comment: "UPnP Device Host" service is disabled -- I've shut off a lot of services I don't want. I'm concerned that it's my program, and I can't control it since I don't know what's causing it.